# Blank space in Footter with Stargazer Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am facing a problem with Stargazer Wordpress Theme. When I open any post, a huge blank space shows below the footer. How can I resolve this problem?

Site: http://goo.gl/5gV40y
Theme installed: http://themehybrid.com/themes/stargazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the embed-wrap has a padding-bottom of 56.25%

```
.embed-wrap {
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 30px;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

The reason it is that big is because when you click to add a comment more information appears (name email etc) so that extra space is filled, but you can change the padding-bottom to make the whitespace smaller, but if you add a comment with a few lines then the  Notify me of follow-up comments via email, post, comment etc will be cut off.